# Запуск python-скрипта с помощью другого python-скрипта

Tags: python

У меня есть два файла python: main.py и test.py
Я использую cmd, чтобы запустить каждый из них, у меня получается две консоли, со скриптами, которые работают в фоне(это б оты).
Возможно ли, с помощью python, запускать другие python скрипты отдельно? Например, я запускаю start.py, а он запускает main.py и test.py в новых консолях.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй import метода из второго скрипта, и потом вызови этот метод в первом

Answer (score 1):

Можно это реализовать с помощью импортов нужных файлов. Для этого файл `start.py` должен выглядеть так:

```py
import main
import test
```

Comment: Это не совсем, то что мне нужно. Нужен способ, который позволит запустить новую консоль и запустить в ней нужный скрипт. Я пишу бота, который для управления ПК дистанционно. Бот будет иметь возможность запускать python скрипты, отдельно от себя, как если бы я это сам сделал, открыл консоль и запустил первый скрипт, затем открою новую консоль и запущу второй скрипт и они спокойно работают в фоне

Answer (score 1):

### Если нужно запустить python скрипт в отдельном окне то можно сделать так:

main.py

```
import os
os.system("start cmd /k python test.py")
```

test.py

```
print('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

main.py

```
exec(open('test.py').read())
```

test.py

```
print('test')
```

Comment: Это не совсем, то что мне нужно. Используя данный способ, скрипт запускается в той же консоли. Нужен способ, который позволит запустить новую консоль и запустить в ней нужный скрипт.
Я пишу бота, который для управления ПК дистанционно. Бот будет иметь возможность запускать python скрипты, отдельно от себя, как если бы я это сам сделал, открыл консоль и запустил первый скрипт, затем открою новую консоль и запущу второй скрипт и они спокойно работают в фоне.

Answer (score 0):

```
Main.py
print('hello') #тут может быть любой код

Launcher.py
exec(open('Main.py').read())
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

> Возможно ли, с помощью python, запускать другие python скрипты
> отдельно?

Я думаю, что python-модуль *multyprocessing* вполне удовлетворит Вашим запросам:

> **multiprocessing — Process-based parallelism**
>
> Introduction
>
> multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an
> API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package
> offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping
> the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads.
> Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully
> leverage multiple processors on a given machine. It runs on both Unix
> and Windows.